# How to get the parent element (not just the window) of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392146/close-jquery-ui-dialog-from-iframe), but my setup is a little different.

I've written this function:

```
function ShowDialog(url, width, height, id, options) {
    var self = arguments.callee;
    if(!self.dialogs) self.dialogs = {};

    var src = url + (url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + '_popup=1';
    if(id) src += '&_field=' + encodeURIComponent(id);

    if(url in self.dialogs === false) {
        var defaults = {
            width: width,
            height: height,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            closeText: 'Close'
        };

        self.dialogs[url] = $('<div/>')
            .html('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" src="'+src+'">Your browser does not support iframes.</iframe>')
            .dialog(options ? $.extend(defaults, options) : defaults);
    } else {
        if(self.dialogs[url].data('reload')) {
            self.dialogs[url].data('reload', false).children('iframe').attr('src', src);
        }
        self.dialogs[url].dialog('open');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Which I use like this:

```
<button onclick="return ShowDialog('/companies/add', 400, 320, 'id_company');">New</button>
```

When you click the button, it opens a dialog with an iframe containing a form. When you submit the form, it redirects to another page which just contains a script which is supposed to close the dialog.

In the other question, he has the ID of the iframe so he can find it, and then call `.dialog('close')`. I've generated my iframe on the fly, so I don't know how to access it.

However, I know that my iframe always sits inside a div which has the `.dialog` object... there should be a way to get the parent element of an iframe from within that iframe, no?

Anyone know how?

---

Can we perhaps find it doing something like

```
window.parent.jQuery(this).parent()
```

? I don't know what `this` needs to be though. Some kind of reference to itself... `window` didn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[window.frameElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.frameElement) gives you the IFrame element

```
var parent = $(window.frameElement).parent();
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Hopefully it's cross-browser compatible.

Comment: I think it is fairly compatible as i'm using it in most of my projects.

Comment: @Sarath: Mark is talking about `cross-browser` compatibility. You are right, it is not `cross-domain` compatible. (in fact no javascript code is, unless you present `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your response header)

Answer (score 2):

inside your iframe you can get the parent DOM like this:

```
window.parent.frames[0].parentNode;
```

this assumes the parent window has only 1 iframe in it, that iframe being the one you are making this call from

Well here is perhaps (untested) another way to do this, create a function in parent window like:

```
var findParent = function() {
    return $(this).parent();
}
```

then inside the iframe do :

```
window.parent.findParent.call(window);
```

Again untested :-)

OK 3rd attempt.

in your `ShowDialog` function instead of `return false` do :

`return self;`

then in your iframe cache the return in a variable so your button would look like this:

`<button onclick="obj = ShowDialog('/companies/add', 400, 320, 'id_company'); return false;">New</button>`

so somewhere in your iframe before this button you'd have a `var obj;`;

then whenever you need the parent of the iframe you could do:

`obj.dialogs[window.location.pathname];`

this IMO should return the parent of the iframe.

again untested :D

Comment: Yeah...but I don't like making that assumption.

Comment: why not window.frameElement? (see my answer for ref.)

Comment: i didnt know of its existence, now i learned something new ^_^ tashakkor!

Answer (score 2):

Just an extension on the [**selected answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726412/how-to-get-the-parent-element-not-just-the-window-of-an-iframe#6726709) by [valipour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/452830/valipour), which, as far as I know, works great. However, before I happened upon this method, I had to "invent" a way that would be cross-browser using jQuery.

The solution I often found was `parent.document`. The problem here is, "what if I have multiple iFrames?"

Thus the following snippet!

```
var parIframe = $(parent.document).find('iframe')
        .filter(function(i){ return $(this).contents()[0] == $(document)[0] });
```

The `.filter` method is used to compare the contents of each iFrame in the parent window to the contents of the current iFrame, thus returning only the iFrame window you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is about as good as we can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = window.parent.jQuery;
$('.ui-dialog-content').filter(function(){return $(this).dialog('isOpen');}).dialog('close').data('reload', true);
</script>
```

It should allow multiple iframes and jQuery UI dialogs on the page as long as 2 aren't open at the same time (which should never be the case).

---

Revised, with `valipour`'s suggestion.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = window.parent.jQuery;
{% if popup_field %}
$('#{{popup_field|escapejs}}').val('{{value|escapejs}}').addClass('selected').focus();
{% endif %}
$(window.frameElement).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close').data('reload', true);
</script>
```

(This is a Django template)