# Close parent iframe window (jquery ui dialog) from within iframe, on different domains due to load balancing

Tags: jquery, iframe, cross-domain, jquery-ui-dialog, load-balancing

I've got a jQuery UI dialog with an iframe inside. I'm loading another page inside the iframe, which is not on the same domain as the parent. The pages are two different systems, System1 (the parent) and System2 (the child inside the iframe).

What I want to do is to add a button on the iframed page which calls JS/jQuery to close the acctual dialog window on the parent page.

Something like they do here: [Close jQuery UI Dialog from Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392146/close-jquery-ui-dialog-from-iframe)

Problem is, this only works when both pages are on the same domain, due to [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Here's my current button, which works fine when both systems are on the same domain:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="$('#myDialog', window.parent.document).hide();" value="X" />
```

The sites/systems could actually be on the same server and domain, but I'm using a load balancer to move traffic around between 3 different servers. 
So there are two systems, each running on three servers. Below, the ports correspond to the different systems (91 = System1, 92 = System2).

I.e.

- http://Server1.myHost.com:91
- http://Server1.myHost.com:92
- http://Server2.myHost.com:91
- http://Server2.myHost.com:92
- http://Server3.myHost.com:91
- http://Server3.myHost.com:92

These systems are load balanced by going to http://System1.myHost.com and http://System2.myHost.com, and the load balancer decides which server to send the user to.

The problem is: when the user goes to http://System1.myHost.com (which for example is actually on Server1) and jQuery/iframe is trying to load the matching System2 site (in this case also on Server1), Javascript thinks that http://System1.myHost.com (which is actually http://Server1.myHost.com:91) and http://Server1.myHost.com:92 are on two different domains.

Somehow I need to trick the Javascript to think that the load balancer address is the same as the actual server address, but I don't know how....

Any ideas on how to solve this? =)

Answer (score 0):

You can't "trick" JavaScript into ignoring the same origin policy, if you could such a policy would be useless.

Load balancing should be transparent to the end user. You should consider using a front-end cache system such as Velocity or Memcached in front of the load-balanced servers.