# How to close jQuery dialog when button inside iFrame is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dialog

i have a jQuery dialog an iFrame is added to dialog when it is opened.
how to ***close*** this dialog wen a button(button present in HTML of iFrame) is clicked.

I tried to get contents inside iFrame using `contents()` but what i was getting is `[object object]`

Many people have already mentioned that we cant access content of cross domain , here no other domain involved at all.

Comment: Same question here with the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392146/close-jquery-ui-dialog-from-iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.parent.$("#dialogDiv").dialog('close');
```

That's solves the problem..

Comment: What if an IFrame is cross domain?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways.

From inside the iframe itself:

```
$('button#closeDialog').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog', top.document).dialog('close');
}
```

From inside your base page:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('button#closeDialog').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog).dialog('close');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#yourIframeId").contents().find("#buttonId").click(function(){
    $("#dialogId" ).dialog( "close" );
});
```

or the on delegate

```
$(document).on('click',"#buttonId",function(){
    $("#dialogId" ).dialog( "close" );
});
```

Comment: thank you for helping ... i used     window.parent.$("#dialogDiv").dialog('close'); now its working smooth

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple and tested solution :

```
window.parent.jQuery('#popId').hide();
```

Comment: This line of code might look like dialog closed, but hiding it from UI is **not closing**, There might be an event attached for dialog **onClose** .