# Bind to event of control within .load() div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-loading

I have a jQuery UI dialog whose content is populated using .load(), and then displayed.  What I need to do is somehow bind to a button within the loaded HTML to close that dialog.

Code:

```
<div id="popup">
    <div id="popupContent"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#popupContent").load('some_URL_within_site_that_has_a_button', function () {
        $("#popup").dialog("open");
    });
</script>
```

I've tried a few different things, w/o success:

```
$("#popupContent").find(".CloseButton").on("click", function () {
    alert("this worked");
});
$(".CloseButton").on("click", function () {
    alert("this worked");
});
```

Any ideas on how to bind to the dynamically loaded control events?

Comment: CloseButton exists in the loaded content?

Answer (score 2):

You are close:

```
$("#popup")
    .dialog("open")
    .on("click", ".CloseButton", function() { ... });
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get this working.  I ended up using the solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392146/close-jquery-ui-dialog-from-iframe.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your jQuery UI dialog was in an IFRAME? Well no wonder my code didn't work. :) That was pretty important information to leave out.

Comment: The dialog isn't actually in an IFRAME, it's just like the code I put in the original question.  The dialog div wraps the content div, which has the content loaded using .load().  Does calling .load() on a div basically convert it to an IFRAME?