# Close jquery dialog from iFrame with external html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, iframe

I am trying to close a jQuery ui dialog from an iframe with an external html inside.

My code looks like the following:

JS code in my main html to create the dialog when I click on a button:

```
function createDialog() {
        return $("<div id='personal-popup' class='dialog' title='Copia de archivos'></div>")
        .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="copy.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
        .dialog({
            resizable: true,
            height: 447.59999990463257,
            width: 993.5999999046326,
            modal: true
        });
    }
```

JS code inside the other html (copy.html)

```
function copiarArchivos() {


$.mobile.loading('show',{
  text: "Copiando",
  textVisible: true,
  theme: "a",
  html: ""
});

var result = [];

var allOptions = $("#select-custom-19");

$("#select-custom-19 option:selected").each(function () {

var $this = $(this);
var selText = $this.text();
$this.prop("selected", false);
result.push(selText);
});

allOptions.selectmenu('refresh', true);

$.ajax ({
  url: "php/copia.php",
  type: "post",
  data: {"params": result},
  success: function(response) {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
        //I want to close the dialog here when the ajax function success
        $(window.parent.document).find("#personal-popup").dialog('close');
    }

}); 
}
```

I have followed the answer to this question: [Close jQuery UI Dialog from Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392146/close-jquery-ui-dialog-from-iframe), but it didn´t work for me.

--- EDIT ---

The JS function which is going to be called from the iFrame, allocated in the mane html (index.html)

```
function closeDialog(){
    console.log("Im working!!");
    document.getElementById("personal-popup").dialog("close");
    }
```

The JS call from the iframe (copy.html)

```
$.ajax ({
  url: "php/copia.php",
  type: "post",
  data: {"params": result},
  success: function(response) {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
        window.parent.closeDialog();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

from inside the iframe you can access `window.parent`.

This means that in your main frame you could have:

`window.closeDialog = function(){//Do stuff}`

Anf then in your iframe have:

`window.parent.closeDialog();`

Comment: I have followed what you have said but still didn´t work for me. I have added the following js fucntion: 

function closeDialog(){
  document.getElementById("personal-popup").dialog("close");
  }

Comment: try adding `console.log("Im working!!")` into the function to see if it is called correctly :)

Comment: I dont see anything in the console but the ajax call it`s done because i can see the files copied in my directory... A little bit strange...

Comment: This means the function is not being called. try putting the function in the iframe inside a `$(document).ready(function(){//function here})`

Comment: The ajax call its being called, I am able to see how $.mobile.loading hides, what is not being called is the js function which is the main html. Anyway, if I put the function inside my second-html (copy.html) i am not able to access the dialog div, do i?

Comment: Yeah of course! Tell me what you should need, html files, php files, both?

Comment: The js in the response from your call and also the function in your main page that you are trying to call :)

Comment: I have edited the answer, if you need more tell me. Very thanks for your help!