# Close bootstrap children modal from the iframe

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I have multiple bootstrap modals which open one inside another.

When a modal window opens, it has an `iframe` in which we may open another modal.

Let's say we have the following hierarchy.

```
-- document
---- modal 1 with iframe 1
------ modal 2 with iframe 2
```

What I want is to close `modal 2` window from the `iframe 2`. As an example, if I have a Close modal window button in `iframe 2`, if I click it I need it to close the `modal 2`.

I can use jQuery too.

Later edit: I don't know the parent modal ID.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close jQuery UI Dialog from Iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392146/close-jquery-ui-dialog-from-iframe)

Comment: Several potential solutions in that question. Where do you want the code to live?

Comment: I want to live in the parent. Regarding the duplicate, the problem is that I don't have access to the ID of the modal window.

Comment: What parent? `#modal2`?

Comment: The close button is in `iframe2`. When I click it, I want my `modal2` to close.