# How to close jquery ui dialog when clicking on link inside the dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog

I've made a terms and conditions page. I want to make it appear in a jQuery dialog.

I declare a variable for the dialog:

```
var $dialog = $('#TCsWindow').html('<iframe style="border: 0px;" src="importantInformation.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>').hide();
```

and then create a function to open the dialog:

```
    function opendialog(page) {
    $dialog.dialog({
        title: "",
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: 'dialog_fixed TCdialog centered',
        modal: true,
        height: 500,
        width:400,
        responsive: true,
        draggable:true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $('#TCsWindow').css('overflow', 'hidden'); //this line does the actual hiding
            }
        });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

and finally attach a click() event to an element on the page:

```
    $("#TCLink").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    opendialog("importantInformation.html");
});
```

The problem I have is that there is a link in the importantInformation.html page which when clicked just needs to close the dialog. The link has an id of "closeTC":

```
    $("#closeTC").click(function(event){
    $dialog.close();
});
```

but what happens is that the actual containing page loads inside the iFrame. It seems that the event.preventDefault(); is being ignored.

Can anyone shed any light as to where I'm going wrong? The default close "x" on the dialog works just fine, but I don't know how to find out how that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the jQuery `.dialog("close")` method from the parent:

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4392545/6525260) for reference.

**The Code**

```
$(parent.document).find('#TCsWindow').dialog( "close" );
```

Comment: That's great Arnav - thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The dialog is in the parent window and not inside the iframe to access an element in the parent window from an iframe you can use `parent`.

```
$(parent.document).find('#TCsWindow').dialog( "close" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)